# how to assign value to in integer with JOptionPane?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

i declared a class
then in that class i declared an int x and array of strings option
i created a constructor of class 
in the consructor i used JOptionPane to choose from 3 options
i want to assign int value to x for each option chosen

```
class A extends JFrame implements ActionListner, TextListener {
    ..........
    int x;
    String[] option = {"AA", "BB", "CC"};

    A() {
        ..........
        int x = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Choose from", "Choose", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, option, option[0]);
    }

    public void B() {
        if(x==2) {
            ......
        }
public static void main(String[] args) {
   A lol = new A(arg[0]);
}
```

sorry cant disclose full code
now when i choose option 3 (to assign value 2 to x) ,the function in B does not execute
but when i assign the value 2 to x while declaring it, B always executes(even when i choose any other option in dialog box)

any ideas what am i doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring a local variable in the constructor with the same name with the class varibale x, remove the keyword int.

```
A() {
   x = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Choose from", "Choose", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, option, option[0]);
}
```